# Read from property file in interface

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

i was wondering if it's possible to initialize a constant in an interface from a property file using java or using spring messageSource, or such thing is not possible
please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

```
public interface Foo {
    String a = Properties.getProperty("foo"); // public static final by default
}
```

However, that means that `Properties.getProperty(..)` has to be a static method which relies on an already initialized message source (statically again). Depending on the project and the frameworks you use this might not be the best option.

Answer (score 2):

You could initialise a bean via a configuration which includes a `final` member. Since it's final you can assign to it during construction/initialisation and it then is immutable.

To configure from a property file using Spring, check out the [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html). That will allow you to initialise Spring beans using one or more property files from your classpath, filesystem, remote services etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible:

```
public static final CONSTANT = System.getProperty("myProperty");
```

Comment: This doesn't get the property from a properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's possible using some static helper method (as was already suggested), I would strongly recommend you not to do so for 2 reasons:

1. That looks like a pretty bad design. If you need a dynamic value - make it a method in the interface. Or use a static helper directly - you will need one anyway to make it work.
2. Constants might be *inlined at compile time*. That shouldn't happen in this particular case - compiler should go with inlining only if it can prove that value won't change between executions, basically if you initialize it with a literal, But there is a tiny chance that it would. Just think how bad will it be - no matter in which environment the progran is running, it picks up some useless value set during compilation, instead of what is configured. (This is rather a theoretical problem, need to say).

Comment: OK, my second point is not relevant - as per Java language spec, 9.3.1: "Every field in the body of an interface must have an initialization expression, which need not be a constant expression. The variable initializer is evaluated and the assignment performed exactly once, when the interface is initialized (§12.4)."
So it's kind of valid approach... but still quite ugly.

Answer (score -1):

by reading a property file like in the example below.

```
int property1;
String otherProperty;
public void loadProperties(File propFile) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(propFile));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.startsWith("Property1=")) {
            property1 = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(10));
        }
        if (line.startsWith("OtherProperty=")) {
            otherProperty = line.substring(14);
        }
    }
}
```